# Show product of limit points $A'\times B' \subset (A\times B)'$ may be strict.

Tags: general-topology

I am currently practicing for the topology qualifying exam and I stumbled to this practice problem: If $A\subset X$, denote $A'$ to be the set of limit points of $A$. Give an example where $A'\times B'\subset (A\times B)'$ is a strict inclusion.

I cannot cook up an example where this happens. Thanks for those who will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=B=\{1/n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$$

is an example.

Comment: Note that $(A \times B)'= (\{0\} \times B) \cup A \times \{0\}$ while $A'\times B'=\{(0,0\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!